# how to make multiple model queries in a class based view(template view)

Tags: python, django, html

I am working on a Django project where i have 3 models Books,Chapters,Topics.

I want to show a list of all the books in the UI. When the user clicks on any of the books, all the chapters will show up and when the user clicks on any of the chapters all the topics will be shown.

I am trying to get this using class based view.
To get the list of books, view.py

```
class read_books(TemplateView):
model = books
template_name='books_list.html'    
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(read_books, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx["books"]=books.objects.all()
    #here is the problem
    ctx["chapters"]=chapters.objects.filter(book_id=4)
    return ctx
```

and books_list.html as

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#child").hide();
        $("#parent").click(function(){
        $("#child").show();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

 <div id="parent" class="nav-width center-block">
    {% for wb in books %}
        <button>{{ wb.book_name }}</button>
        </br></br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>


<div id="child">
    {% for s in chapters %}
    <a href="">{{s.sheet_name}}</a>
    </br></br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now i am in trouble that there will be a list of books which have a id. i want to pass that id 
    'ctx["chapters"]=chapters.objects.filter(book_id=4)'
right now i am passing it manually. can any one suggest and help how to get the id from books model and pass it in this query
Any help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: if you're looking to create a bunch of nested links - did you consider trying this out by implementing django rest framework?

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you want: you say it's working implemented as a (subclass of) `ListView`, so why you want it to "convert" it to a `TemplateView`? isn't it less DRY? Anyway, even if you still want to reimplement it as a `TemplateView`, can't you just encode your queries overriding the `get_context(...)` method and passing the result of your queries to the context? Or do you want something more complicate I'm not getting?

Comment: No sir, I am looking to do this so as to understand the working of class based views properly. Is it not possibble without rest framework i.e. making queries on multiple models.

Comment: Rest Framework has nothing whatsoever to do with this, @Kunkka has introduced a red herring. But like FSp, I am confused about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

you should have something like the below if you want to stick to CBVs

```
class BookList(ListView):
   model = Book

# the below would show the details of particular chapters for a specific book

class BookDetail(DetailView):
   model = Book

#and so on
class chapterList(ListView):
   model = Chapter

on your html - link the urls to each book/chapter by using their respective pks

<a href = '{% url "book" pk = obj.pk %}'></a>
```

Comment: I need to implement the templateview. In the UI, list of books as links should be shown to the user.when the user click on any of the link it will query the chapters model and show the list of chapters.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use the templateview here - you might as well include TemplateName = 'book.html' in the class definition

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say you want to implement your view as a `TemplateView` (but return the same result + some additional queries on different models. You could do the following:

```
# models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    ...

class Model1(models.Model): 
    ...

class ModelN(models.Model):
    ...

# views.py
class BookTemplateView(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(BookTemplateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx["books"] = Book.objects.all()
        ctx["data_1"] = Model1.objects.all() # you can refine this, of course
        ...
        ctx["data_n"] = ModelN.objects.all() # you can refine this, of course

        return ctx
```

and in `Book_list.html` you could write something like (taken from your question):

```
{% for wb in books %}
  <button>{{ wb.book_name }}</button>
  </br></br>
{% endfor %}

...
{% for object in data_1 %}
    ... do something meaningful ...
{% endfor %}
...
{% for object in data_n %}
    ... do something meaningful ...
{% endfor %}
```

Notice that this would work exactly the same if `BookTemplateView` inherited from `ListView`, and then you didn't need to assign `ctx["books"] = Book.objects.all()` (this is the reason why it seems to me a less DRY approach)

Is this close to what you liked to do?